# How to pick multiple files from Android's gallery?

Tags: android, gallery, onactivityresult

i need to open gallery and pick 1-n images OR 1-n videos (2 different intent) from Android's gallery, like the `ACTION_PICK` intent. How can I achieve that? There are some cool library on GitHub for multiple pick or custom gallery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use API 18 or higher, you can add to your `intent.putExtra` like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*,video/*"); //For choosing both images and/or videos
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true); //This should allow multiple selection
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), 1);
```

There is also a GitHub project to build your own GridView with multi selection
Read [here](https://github.com/luminousman/MultipleImagePick)

Comment: I've seen the project but i really don't understand how to import It to mine.

Comment: there isn't any support jar to include that before api 18? Android 4.3 as the minimun Android version supported is creepy.

Comment: So I understand you are using API<18 ?

Comment: With my app i will at least support android 4.0.3 +.

Comment: From what I have researched - your only option is to use a custon library (like I have posted) if using API<18. Pick your battles :-)

Comment: Ok, but how can I add the library you've linked from github on my project, there's no maven, no jar, nothing! :D

Comment: Look in Libs folder - there is a jar there

Answer (score 0):

To pick multiple files from gallery you need to simply modify your intent. For example:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setType("image/*");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(
             Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select"), 1);
```

Please note the **i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);**

Comment: if select video from gallery i can't get the type more over it cause nullpointer error when picking the video